# Creating a custom blog design in Sitefinity 3.7?

Tags: user-controls, blogs, sitefinity, sitefinity-3x

I'm working on a site that requires the layout of the blog to be changed. I read somewhere that I need to map a custom control. Anyone know what this involves? I don't need a fully fledged answer, just some direction.

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a blog post that explains how to do this:
http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/ivan/posts/09-02-23/mapping_a_control_to_use_external_template.aspx

Hope this helps,

Ivan